# Como actualizar header de react js

Tags: reactjs

soy nuevo en react y  al hacer login un usuario quiero que se actualice el header para que aparezcan el correo del usuario en la cabecera, Cual sería el proceso a seguir ? Ya que react no recarga la pagina.

Un Saludo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si haces un login obviamente corroboras los datos enviándolos al backend, pues trae esos datos y pintalos en pantallas, cual es problema en hacer eso?

Comment: Si tu header recibe props, puedes añadir un método de ciclo de vida shouldComponentUpdate en caso de que aunque vengan nuevas no te esté renderizando lo que toca. Para más información, visita https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate